# Remove commas in a row so it came up with clean commas string

Tags: javascript

For example i got that string `1500,,,4000,5000` i need to delete `,,` commas, so this is came up with `1500,4000,5000`

Another example: `,Banana,,Apple,,,,Watermelon,` to became as clean as possible `Banana,Apple,Watermelon`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: PLease show us your attempt. THere are tons of ways of doing this.

Comment: `.split(',').filter(Boolean).join(',')` - what you really want is not to remove subsequent commas, but rather remove empty elements from your comma-delimited list.

Comment: If you created the string with `array.join(',')`, why don't you filter out empty values from the array before joining them? Or not put empty values in the array in the first place?

Comment: If this is data from a CSV file you may not want to remove the commas like this if you want to preserve its structural integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple regular expression of `,{2,}` will match any instance of 2 more more commas in a row. All matches of that can be replaced with a single comma.

```js
function stripMultiCommas(str){
  return str
    .replace(/,{2,}/g, ',') //replaces 2 or more commas with a single comma
    .replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g,'') //remove commas at the beginning or end of a string
}

console.log(stripMultiCommas('1500,,,4000,5000,,6000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,7000'));
console.log(stripMultiCommas(',Banana,,Apple,,,,Watermelon,'));
```

Comment: This does not work for the second example.

Comment: You are right. I have updated my answer to fix this now.